# Организовать Псевдорелевантный SQL-поиск

Tags: mysql, sql, like, полнотекстовый-поиск

у меня есть "живой поиск" который ищет по базе через такой:
sql запрос

```
SELECT s.name1 value, s.text1 descr, i.name icon FROM prefix_shop s JOIN prefix_images i ON s.id = i.element_id WHERE i.module_name = 'shop' and s.trash = '0' and s.act1 = '1' and s.name1 LIKE '%{$keyword}%' GROUP BY s.name1
```

Нашёл подходящие объяснение как это организовать:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE
      BINARY MyField = 'Full Relevance'
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE
      MyField = 'Full Relevance'
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE
      BINARY MyField LIKE '%Full Relevance%'
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE
      MyField LIKE '%Full Relevance%'
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE
      (BINARY MyField LIKE '%Full%') AND (BINARY MyField LIKE '%Relevance%')
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE
      (MyField LIKE '%Full%') AND (MyField LIKE '%Relevance%')
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE
      (BINARY MyField LIKE '%Full%') OR (BINARY MyField LIKE '%Relevance%')
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE
      (MyField LIKE '%Full%') OR (MyField LIKE '%Relevance%')
```

но моих знаний не хватает как переделать мой запрос со всеми параметрами которые он имеет сейчас, в структуру запроса из примера.

**UPDATE**

Может кто подскажет как в данном коде разбить `$keyword` на массив, что бы каждое слово было отдельно, а не предложением. Сейчас если прилетит `Болт нарезной` то и по `like` он будет искать `%болт нарезной%` а нужно что бы каждое слово искалось отдельно `%Болт% %нарезной%`

```
    function serachForKeyword($keyword) {

      $results = array();

        $db = getDbConnection();
      $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT s.name1 value, s.text1 descr, i.name icon FROM prefix_shop s JOIN prefix_images i ON s.id = i.element_id WHERE i.module_name = 'shop' and s.trash = '0' and s.act1 = '1' and s.name1 LIKE '%{$keyword}%' GROUP BY s.name1 limit 0, 25");     



        $isQueryOk = $stmt->execute();
        if ($isQueryOk) {


       while (($row = $stmt->fetch() ) )
           {
            $results[] = array(
             'icon' => $row['icon'],
             'descr' => $row['descr'],
             'value' => $row['value']
              );
           }

        } else {
            trigger_error('Error executing statement.', E_USER_ERROR);
        }
         $db = null; 

    return $results;
}
```

Comment: Не хотите попробовать sphinxsearch для своей задачи?

Comment: @danil нет возможности установки его на локальную машину, установку на хостинг я не нашёл документации, если поможете ссылкой буду благодарен.

Comment: вы можете скачать подходящий дистрибутив на [официальном сайте](http://sphinxsearch.com/downloads/release/). Установка ничего не требует, а по настройке есть много статей в гугле, [например вот](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-sphinx-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: @danil спасибо, буду пробовать, но данный вопрос оставлю открытым, может возможно будет сделать то о чем я говорил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализовал через `replace`

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT s.name1 value, s.text1 descr, i.name icon FROM prefix_shop s JOIN prefix_images i ON s.id = i.element_id WHERE i.module_name = 'shop' and s.trash = '0' and s.act1 = '1' and s.name1 LIKE replace('%{$keyword}%',' ','%') GROUP BY s.name1 limit 0, 25");
```